# Memory Management in H2O

Tags: h2o

I am curious to know how memory is managed in H2O. 
Is it completely 'in-memory' or does it allow swapping in case the memory consumption goes beyond available physical memory? Can I set -mapperXmx parameter to 350GB if I have a total of 384GB of RAM on a node? I do realise that the cluster won't be able to handle anything other than the H2O cluster in this case.
Any pointers are much appreciated, Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

1. H2O-3 stores data completely in-memory in a distributed column-compressed distributed key-value store.
2. No swapping to disk is supported.
3. Since you are alluding to `mapperXmx`, I assume you are talking about running H2O in a YARN environment.  In that case, the total YARN container size allocated per node is:

   mapreduce.map.memory.mb = mapperXmx * (1 + extramempercent/100)

`extramempercent` is another (rarely used) command-line parameter to h2odriver.jar.  Note the default `extramempercent` is 10 (percent).

`mapperXmx` is the size of the Java heap, and the extra memory referred to above is for additional overhead of the JVM implementation itself (e.g. the C/C++ heap).

YARN is extremely picky about this, and if your container tries to use even one byte over its allocation (mapreduce.map.memory.mb), YARN will immediately terminate the container.  (And for H2O-3, since it's an in-memory processing engine, the loss of one container terminates the entire job.)

You can set `mapperXmx` and `extramempercent` to as large a value as YARN has space to start containers.